# Writting to 0xB800 in 16 bit mode shows a "G" and a quote

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader, real-mode

As an educational project, I decided to write an extremely simple boot-loader. A boot-loader that doesn't boot anything, but shows a message. For some reason, I can write to video memory, but the last letter's ASCII value is 7 bigger than it's supposed to be and a quote follows the message.

Here's my code:

```
bits 16 ; 16-bit Real Mode
org 0x7c00 ; BIOS boot origin 

jmp main ;Jump to start main() entry-point 

main:
    mov ax, 0xB800
    mov ds, ax
    mov si, 0x0
    mov [si], byte 'A'
    add si, 2
    mov [si], byte 'A'
    add si, 2
    mov [si], byte 'A'
    add si, 2
    mov [si], byte 'A'
    add si, 2
    mov [si], byte 'A'

    hlt

times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

Here's the output:

```
AAAAH"
```

Comment: Read up on what `hlt` does. Hint: an interrupt can wake it, so your program continues and probably hits some instruction that has that effect. PS: learn to use a debugger.

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: Try using jmp $ instead of halt.

Comment: Or `cli` `endloop: hlt` `jmp endloop`

Comment: One other possibility is that the problem is with `jmp main`. I'm not sure what environment you are running (a real computer?) and what type of media is being booted. It is possible if it is a real system you are booting, the BIOS may have overwritten what it thinks was the BIOS Parameter Block (BPB) and happened to alter your code to print different characters. I'd remove the `jmp main` as being the first instruction of the bootloader since you don't have a BPB.

Comment: instead of `mov [si], byte 'A'; add si, 2` consider using `mov di, 'a'; stosb; stosb; stosb; stosb` to write the characters. Saves some code.

Comment: @FUZxxl I think you mean `mov al, 'a'; stosb...`

Comment: @sami of course I do.

Comment: @FUZxxl: that's not the same. The text mode VRAM consist of byte pairs [glyph code, color value], so your `4x stosb` would write only two 'A' on screen, with weird colors (too lazy to figure out which colours would 'A' set :) ). So the correct possible variant is `(set es:di to point to b800:somewhere) mov ax,0cc41h stosw stosw stosw stosw`, where `cc` is some color value. (41h is 'A').  OP: isn't it nice, how the computer can moan upon booting? :D

Comment: @Ped7g Oh yes, I totally forgot about that quirk.

Comment: That `AAAAH"` is just a scream of despair, from the BIOS. <g>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, changing hlt to jmp $ solved the problem. Here's the working code:

```
bits 16
org 0x7c00

main:
    mov ax, 0xB800
    mov ds, ax
    mov si, 0x0
    mov [si], byte 'A'
    add si, 2
    mov [si], byte 'A'
    add si, 2
    mov [si], byte 'A'
    add si, 2
    mov [si], byte 'A'
    add si, 2
    mov [si], byte 'A'

    jmp $

times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```